# Sending email using google api with python

Tags: python

I'm building a python GMAIL API for sending emails, I don't want it to do the authorization automatically, I tried using this code but seems I cant send emails with the token generated with this method.

the code i used,

i tried using this method "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" to get the token instead of using the flow.run_local_server(), but i cant send message with the token generated but when i use the flow.run_loacal_server() to authorize the credentials it works.

the question is, is there any way to use the method I want, which is the code i provided.

```
SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/']
file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


#######################################################################################################
def add_account():
    try:
        folder_path = os.path.join(file_path, 'assets', 'data')
        file_names = [item for item in os.listdir(folder_path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folder_path, item))]
        anum = len(file_names)
        for i in range(anum):
            creds = None
            if os.path.exists(file_path + r'\assets\data\tokens\token{}.pickle'.format(i)):
                with open(file_path + r'\assets\data\tokens\token{}.pickle'.format(i), "rb") as token:
                    creds = pickle.load(token)
                    continue
            if not creds or not creds.valid:
                if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                    creds.refresh(Request())
                    continue
                else:
                    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(file_path + r'\assets\data\cred{}.json'.format(i),
                                                                    SCOPES,
                                                                    redirect_uri='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob')
                    authorization_url, _ = flow.authorization_url(prompt='consent')
                    
                    
                    print("Authorize this app by visiting the following URL:")
                    print(authorization_url)
                    code = input("Enter the authorization code: ")
                    creds = flow.fetch_token(code=code)
                    # return build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
                    
                    session = flow.authorized_session()
                    print(session.get('https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me').json())
                    
                with open(file_path + r'\assets\data\tokens\token{}.pickle'.format(i), "wb") as token:
                    pickle.dump(creds, token)
                    continue
            return build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'[Something went wrong] {g}Message >>{e}')
add_account()
```